# request.POST.get(variable) returns None when trying to receive by id

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Ok so, help me out here I'm going crazy!

I have 4 questions each with a radio button name set to the question id and the value set to the answer id to get the answer's id and use it to get the user's submitted answer to check if it is correct or not.

views.py

```
def sampleQuestions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        userInformation = UserInformation.objects.get(user=user)
        allAnswers = Answers.objects.all()
        allQuestions = Questions.objects.all()
        i = 0
        for q in Questions.objects.all():
            print(q.id) #returns 1
            answerID = request.POST.get(q.id) #returns None
            print(answerID)
            answer = Answers.objects.get(id=answerID)
            print(answer)
```

template.html

```
{% for q in questions %}
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td> {{q.question}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% for a in answers %}
                {% if a.answerForQuestion == q%}
                <tr>     
                    <td> <input type="radio" name = "{{q.id}}" value="{{a.id}}"> {{a.answer}}</td> 
                    {{q.id}}
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </fieldset>
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the request in your browser's developer tools' network tab? You should be able to see exactly what data is being posted. Also, you have a rogue `</fieldset>` in there with no opening `<fieldset>`.

Comment: @Dave I removed the rogue fieldset thanks. I am unsure how to look at that I just test it with print statements and have found out when I enter '1' it works but even if I enter a variable with the value '1' it still doesn't work which is very weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` id a python dict with key as string. so provide a string in key lookup.

```
answerID = request.POST.get(str(q.id)) #returns None
```